# Should I choose Hiberlite for integrating SQLite into my Win/iOS application?

Tags: sql, ios, hibernate, sqlite, orm

I am a composer by profession and my computer science skills are limited though I program quite a bit of the software that I use.

What are the most reasonable ways to approach SQLite integration as a file format and database in an iOS app (it also needs to run on windows, but that is a secondary concern)?

I have been researching Hiberlite, which looks fantastic, but it seems to be little used and apparently it doesn't run well on embedded systems (iOS?) and chokes up when thousands of objects are in play. I haven't been able to get a sense of how severe those bottle necks are when running under those conditions.

The settings of thousands of objects (~50,000 though that number could expand) would be read every 1-10 seconds and written periodically.  Read performance is more critical as write operations can stutter with out effecting the core operation of the app.

Given those conditions, how should I approach SQLite?  My understanding is that without something like Hiberlite the entire database (many millions of entries) must be read and rewritten for every entry, is that less efficient.  If that is the best approach is there a good resource to follow for implementing it?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  My current software that I rely on is beyond buggy and needs refactoring, but due to my inexperience I am having a difficult time finding information about a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you've probably found a solution for this by now, but I've been interested myself in embedding SQLite on Android and IOS, and I came across **many** C++-based ORM solutions.

[Hiberlite](http://code.google.com/p/hiberlite) looked possibly not fully mature (I didn't readily see a method of returning subsets of data, which is fairly standard). A framework which did draw my attention was the [POCO:Data ORM library](http://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-DataUserManual.html). It's based on the stream-based mechanism used in [SOCI ORM](http://soci.sourceforge.net). The [POCO library](http://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-DataUserManual.html) is modular and optimised for embedded environments (I believe it also has a minimal external dependencies). Wikipedia has an article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POCO_C%2B%2B_Libraries), they outline some of its users, of which [OpenFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc) is one.

The [WT ORM](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) also looked pretty interesting.

I'm listing some of the other C++ ORM frameworks I found here, in no particular order:

http://soci.sourceforge.net
[webtoolkit WT DBO ORM](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/blog/2009/11/26/wt__dbo__an_orm__c___style)
http://debea.net
http://www.qxorm.com
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/litesql
http://otl.sourceforge.net
http://cppcms.com/sql/cppdb
http://dtemplatelib.sourceforge.net
http://code.google.com/p/qdjango

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just got my MacBook in the mail and am still researching ORMs. At the moment I am torn between wt:Dbo (which I don't mind paying for) and SOCI.  I was hot on QxOrm but Qt has scared me off.  Part of my dilemma is that I want to use a Dependency Injection library (phs sauce) and I'm not sure which would work best in conjunction as most ORM's handle the instantiation and memory management on their own. I am still in the planning stage but I hope to get my hands dirty in the next week or two. If you have any insights as you get deeper in I would love to hear them.